# Get Google Ads content by PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, web-crawler

I want to get Google Ads content on a webpage.
I am using phantomJS, when i render an images, i can see google ads blocks.
But when I get source (html), it is only javascript code.

My simple code.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var page = require('webpage').create();
var url = "http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2016/04/oracle-undo-tablespace/";

page.open(url);

page.onLoadFinished = function()
{

    fs.write("source.htm", page.content, 'w');
    page.render('render.png');
    phantom.exit();

};
```

Render image have Google ads contents.

[image]

But HTML source:

```
<p>In the above example, we have two UNDO tablespace listed. But only one of them can be active and used by the system. The other one is currently not used.</p>
<p>So, the best way to view the current valid UNDO tablespace is by using “show parameter” as shown below.</p>
<center>
  <div style="margin-left:2px; margin-top:10px; margin-bottom:10px; ">

    <!-- AD BLOCK -->

 <script async="" src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- TGS Inside Content -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle" style="display: inline-block; width: 300px; height: 250px;" data-ad-client="ca-pub-8090601437064582" data-ad-slot="8643685131" data-adsbygoogle-status="done"><ins id="aswift_1_expand" style="display:inline-table;border:none;height:250px;margin:0;padding:0;position:relative;visibility:visible;width:300px;background-color:transparent"><ins id="aswift_1_anchor" style="display:block;border:none;height:250px;margin:0;padding:0;position:relative;visibility:visible;width:300px;background-color:transparent"><iframe width="300" height="250" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" vspace="0" hspace="0" allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="true" onload="var i=this.id,s=window.google_iframe_oncopy,H=s&amp;&amp;s.handlers,h=H&amp;&amp;H[i],w=this.contentWindow,d;try{d=w.document}catch(e){}if(h&amp;&amp;d&amp;&amp;(!d.body||!d.body.firstChild)){if(h.call){setTimeout(h,0)}else if(h.match){try{h=s.upd(h,i)}catch(e){}w.location.replace(h)}}" id="aswift_1" name="aswift_1" style="left:0;position:absolute;top:0;"></iframe></ins></ins></ins>
 <script>
 (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>

    <!-- END AD BLOCK -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the page output, there looks to be an iframe with name 'aswift_1'. This in turn contains an iframe called 'google_ads_frame2'. I'm not familiar with the structure of google ads, but at a glance, these look to be used to output the ad content.

If you want to fetch this iframe content using phantomjs, code like the following would work:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var page = require('webpage').create();
var url = "http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2016/04/oracle-undo-tablespace/";

page.open(url,  function(status) {
    if ('success' !== status) {
        console.log("Error");
    } else {
        page.switchToChildFrame('aswift_1');
        page.switchToChildFrame('google_ads_frame2');
        fs.write("test-google-source.htm", page.frameContent, 'w');
        page.render('test-google-render.png');
    }
    phantom.exit();
});
```